# Creating object on different model with logic to another model

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have 2 models,
One is `Order` and the other is `Item`.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Un Finished', 'Un Finished'),
    ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
    ('Assigned', 'Assigned For PickUp'),
    ('Picked Up', 'Picked Up'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Un Finished')
```

#item

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["updated"]
```

If any of the object status in the Order model changes to `Completed` I want to automatically create the object in the Item models. Let's say

Model Order contains and object:

```
{id: 12 , product : "Product Name", status : "Completed"}
```

Then here I want to update the Item with an object containing that information.
How I can do this in a simpler way?

I found some articles that suggest using Django signals but I'm new to Django and need little help to reproduce the solution.

Comment: 1)first you can have a foreignkey to your item that is related to the order. <br>                                          2)while changing the status you can check whether the status is completed or not  ,if it is then create the item model. i do not think that you really need a signal for this.

Comment: They arent related to each other, it's just an action to update the item if an order gets completed

Comment: then use the second approach 2).

Comment: You mean to override self.save() method ?

Comment: are you changing the status using the django admin or using a view?

Comment: will be changed from Django admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243744/discussion-between-thierno-amadou-sow-and-atropa-belladona).